# Spring 3 and JUnit 4 (autowiring)

Tags: spring, junit4, autowired

I am new to Spring MVC and JUnit. Basically I want to autowire the service class and this class should be loaded in spring context.

Service

```
    @Service 
    public class FundService  {
        @Autowired
        FundDAO fundDAO;

        /**
         * @return
         */
        public List getFundDetails(String productId) {

            return fundDAO.getFundDetails(productId);
        }   
    }
```

application-context

```
<beans>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.*" />
</beans>
```

Junit class

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:/WEB-INF/application-context.xml"})
    public class CompensationServiceTest {

        @Autowired
        private FundService fundService;

        @Test
        public void verifyGetCompensationList()
        {
            System.out.println(fundService == null);
        }
    }
```

While executing the test I am getting following exception trace

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.test.admin.service.CompensationServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.admin.service.FundService com.test.admin.service.CompensationServiceTest.fundService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.test.admin.service.FundService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:333)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.admin.service.FundService com.test.admin.service.CompensationServiceTest.fundService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.test.admin.service.FundService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.test.admin.service.FundService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:903)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
        ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `WEB-INF` folder should never be in the classpath; it should be in the file system of the project. So if you use the Maven project structure, that folder would be located relative to the root of your project (i.e., `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`). In that case you would want to declare an XML configuration file in that folder as a file system resource like this:

`@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/application-context.xml")`

Secondly, if this is a test configuration file, you should not store it under `WEB-INF`. Instead, you should store it in the classpath. Following the Maven project structure, this would be `src/test/resources/application-context.xml`, in which case you would use the following declaration in your test:

`@ContextConfiguration("/application-context.xml")`

or

`@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application-context.xml")`

... whichever your prefer, but note that they are equivalent.

Regards and thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

If you use `@Autowire` it means you're creating an application context for your tests, there are several steps to achieve this; Instead of telling you how, I'd like to tell you about the right approach.

Since you're talking about *unit tests* it means the class you're testing is isolated and the injected dependencies have to be mocks, an example next:

The class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class CatalogRest {

    @Autowired
    private CatalogService catalogService;

    @Autowired
    private LoggedUser loggedUser;

    @RequestMapping(value = GET_VIEW_TYPE, method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ViewType>> getViewType() {

        List<ViewType> viewTypes = catalogService.getViewType(loggedUser.getUserId());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ViewType>>(viewTypes, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Now the test:

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CatalogRestTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CatalogRest subject;

    @Mock
    private CatalogService catalogService;

    @Mock
    private LoggedUser loggedUser;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void classAndItsMethodsHaveRequiredAnnotations() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(subject.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class));
        assertTrue(subject.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class));

        Method getViewTypeMethod = subject.getClass().getMethod("getViewType");
        getViewTypeMethod.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void getViewType_whenInvoked_returnsAListOfViewTypes() throws Exception {
        List<ViewType> viewTypes = Arrays.asList(new ViewType());

        when(loggedUser.getUserId()).thenReturn("fake user");
        when(catalogService.getViewType(eq("fake user"))).thenReturn(viewTypes);

        ResponseEntity<List<ViewType>> result = subject.getViewType();

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertNotNull(result.getBody());
        assertTrue(result.getBody().size() == 1);

        verify(catalogService, times(1)).getViewType(eq("fake user"));
    }
```

Do not attempt to use spring for unit testing, it only should be used for `integration testing`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to qualify the Service class with "@Component" annotation for it to be picked during component scan, right?

Comment: @Service also does the same thing. As like component it is also one of the stereo type.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code where you do your bean configuration. The problem here is that Spring is trying to find a concrete class to wire for

```
@Autowired
private FundService fundService;
```

You need to specify the bean Spring should inject in your configuration. For example, doing it in XML you would say:

```
<beans>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.*" />

    <!-- Assuming FundServiceImpl is a class that implement FundService -->
    <bean id="fundService" class="com.test.admin.service.FundServiceImpl"/> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had nested classed / param'ed tests:

**BEFORE**

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestX.class})
public class SimpleTest {

...
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public static class SimpleCheckAddTest{
.....
}

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public static class SimpleCheckRemoveTest{
.....
}

}
```

and got: <.....Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field......> exception like.

**AFTER**

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class SimpleTest {

...
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestX.class})
public static class SimpleCheckAddTest{
.....
}

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestX.class})
public static class SimpleCheckRemoveTest{
.....
}

}
```